# Limite de quantidade na consulta do banco de dados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

```
public IList<DtoContrato> ConsulteListaPorListaDeIds(List<Guid> listaIds)
{
   return Conversor(Persistencia().Where(x => listaIds.Contains(x.Id)));
}
```

Minha questão é, caso a lista de ids possua 100mil registros por exemplo, o nhibernate consegue dividir essa lista em várias de 1000? pois sabemos que na clausula IN do oracle só suporta 1000 registros diferentes.

Qual seria a maneira mais performática de realizar essa consulta?

Pode gerar algum erro sabendo que a Persistência pode estar conectada tanto ao SQL quanto ao ORACLE?

Seria performático usar:?

```
.Or(x => parteDaLista1(x.Id)).Or(x => parteDaLista2(x.Id)).Or(x => parteDaLista3(x.Id))
```

Tem restrição de quantidade de Or que o nhibernate suporta antes de gerar erro no banco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, o Oracle limita que 1000 registros estejam na cláusula `in`.

Não, o nHibernate não "consegue" dividir a lista em várias de 1000. Ele não faz nada "em especial" com o `in`, só passa as informações do banco.

Esse tratamento tem de ser manual. Se você realmente necessita de utilizar mais de 1000 elementos na cláusula `in`, você tem duas opções:

1. Quebrar a lista em "pedaços" de 1000 registros, conforme você citou:

`.Or(x => parteDaLista1(x.Id)).Or(x => parteDaLista2(x.Id)).Or(x => parteDaLista3(x.Id))`

2. Inserir os Ids em uma `global temporary table` e resolvendo tudo através de um select com `joins`. Isso vai lhe permitir o uso de `Foreign Key Constraints`, além de validar por exemplo os Ids, além de uma espécie de histórico deles no seu banco. A indexação seria bem melhor.